# Points for accepting the answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I know there is already some reputation that you gain when you accept answers. Is there something which encourages people to considering accepting answers?

For example if you consistently maintain an accept rate > 85% then you earn some points.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you maintain a reasonable accept rate above 70% the benefit you reap comes in the form of a lack of comments bugging you to accept more answers.

Comment: Yep I agree with you :)

Answer (score 3):

That would be like a manager asking his programmers to produce *n* lines of code every week.